# Using jsp tags in attributes to custom jsp tags

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have a custom JSP tag with an url attribute. How can I pass in the result off invoking another jsp tag to that attribute, specifically using ?

```
<m:customTag url="<spring:url value='/root'>" />
```

The value passed in to url is "" rather than what spring resolves the url to. I have done a workaround using RequestContextAwareTag and getRequestContext().getRequestDataValueProcessor() similar to how the spring url tag works. But I would still like to know if the above code is possible to get working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the var attribute of the url tag.
I think this might help:

```
<spring:url value="/root" var="someUrl">
<m:customTag url="${someUrl}" />
```

Comment: I found out that I could use that solution. However I still wonder if it's possible to directly inline a tag into the attribute off another tag.